# Merge values in foreach loop based on preg match condition

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been trying unsuccessfully to access and manipulate certain name value pairs within an array when in a foreach loop.

My data is in an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [subject] => math
        [price] => 5
        [year] => 2006
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [subject] => reading
        [price] => 7
        [year] => 2007                                              
        [author] => Smith
        [publisher] => Press
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [subject] => reading
        [price] => 9        
        [year] => 2008                                                              
        [author] => Jones
        [copyright] => 1999
    )
```

My code is:

```
$count = count($array); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach($array[$i] as $name => $value) {
                if(preg_match('(subject|price|year)', $name) != 1) { 
                        @$desc .= '-'.$name.'-'.$value;
                } else {
                        $desc = ''; 
                }
                echo $i.' : '.$desc.'<br />';
        }                       
}
```

My desired output from the code above would be:

```
0 : subject-math / price-5 / year-2006
1 : subject-reading / price-7 / year-2007 / author-Smith-publisher-Press
2 : subject-reading / price-9 / year-2008 / author-Jones-copyright-1999
```

The main issue I am facing is that I don't know how to combine & echo out all of the name value pairs that don't match the preg_match condition.  Essentially subject, price and year and common to every record but any of the others I want to be able to access all merged together as one item.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your output? Do you actually want to _echo_ them? Or do you want to store them in an array to process them further?

Comment: How does `sold-33` get outputted?

Comment: @Xatenev - To simplify here, I would like to echo them.  I will be doing other tasks but was trying to simplify the question.  If I can see how to echo them out, I should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: @user3783243 - apologies, I am removing the sold line from the array and the output for simplification.

Comment: What if the author, publisher, etc. has a `-` in their name? Is there some sort of encapsulation you'll be using? Maybe start with https://3v4l.org/K0YZK. I wouldn't use a regex here (you are not really using any regex functionality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It loops through your array, pushing all the key-value pairs into an array and then echo'ing an implode (with `/`) of the array. Values for `subject`, `price` and `year` have their own entries, while all other values are pushed into an array which is then also imploded using `-` to give your desired output. Rather than using `preg_match` to match keys, a simple `in_array` is used instead:

```
foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($d as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, ['subject', 'price', 'year'])) {
            $out[] = "$key-$value";
        }
        else {
            $out['others'][] = "$key-$value";
        }
    }
    if (isset($out['others'])) $out[] = implode('-', $out['others']);
    unset($out['others']);
    echo "$k : " . implode(' / ', $out) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 : subject-math / price-5 / year-2006
1 : subject-reading / price-7 / year-2007 / author-Smith-publisher-Press 
2 : subject-reading / price-9 / year-2008 / author-Jones-copyright-1999
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OJB1m)

Comment: An addition to that: I wouldn't really use `preg_match` here as a simple `in_array($key, ['subject', 'price', 'year']);` should work just fine. Aswell with `preg_match` you get issues with keys like `subject-price`. Its unlikely that this will cause an issue for you but i just wanted to note it.

Comment: @Xatenev good point - I was just copying that part from OPs code. I will update.

Comment: Could probably even do it without the `foreach` and use array key exists on the `d` and if it exists pull its value.

Comment: @user3783243 If you use `array_key_exists` you're effectively looping through the array anyway

Comment: just for info: if you used sample input array, you'll see that you have extra `/` character when your `$out['others']` is empty

Comment: @user1597430 my input data was copy pasted from OPs original question. Thanks for pointing out that he has edited it. I'll update my answer and demo.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - this worked like a charm.  I was getting tripped up on where I was putting the foreach statements.  Very much appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it'll be the most simple implementation:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $item)
{
    $result = array_filter
    ([
        'subject-' . array_shift($item),
        'price-'   . array_shift($item),
        'subject-' . array_shift($item),

        implode('-', $item)
    ]);

    $result = implode(' / ', $result);

    echo "$index: $result\n";
}
```

Comment: I preferred your previous answer. This depends on the order of the elements of the data array being fixed.

Comment: Nah, there's should be always non-boring answer :)